# Cannot request backend after package with app.asar in ElectronJS, Angular, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, express, electron, electron-forge

I am building an app using ElectronJS, NodeJS, and Angular. The issue I am facing is that when I package the app with the option 'asar: false', it works fine and the requests from the Angular frontend to backend work smoothly. However, after packaging with 'asar: true', the frontend cannot make requests to backend (http://localhost:3006) remain pending.

I have been researching for many days, but I haven't found a solution to this problem. I would appreciate any suggestions or help from the community. Thank you.

Header of a request
[image: request pending header]
main.js

```
const {
    app,
    BrowserWindow,
    ipcMain,
    Tray,
    Menu,
    nativeImage,
    dialog,
} = require("electron");
const config = require("./config.json");
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const path = require("path");
const appAsarPath = app.getAppPath();

const backendSvr = require("./src/services/index");
const i18n = new (require("./src/services/trans"))();

const logger = require("./logger");

const appName = "KIN";
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";

let mainWindow, splashWindow, tray, serverProcess;

const log = require("electron-log");
log.transports.file.resolvePath = () =>
    path.join(appAsarPath, "../../logs/main.log");
log.info("App started");

const createMainWindow = async () => {
    log.debug("Start createMainWindow");
    const iconPath = isDev
        ? "src/assets/img/icons/favicon.ico"
        : path.join(appAsarPath, "dist/assets/img/icons/favicon.ico");
    const preloadJSPath = isDev
        ? path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
        : path.join(appAsarPath, "preload.js");
    log.debug(iconPath);
    log.debug(preloadJSPath);

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1024,
        height: 768,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
            enableRemoteModule: false,
            preload: preloadJSPath,
        },
        title: appName,
        icon: iconPath,
    });

    if (isDev) {
        mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:4200");
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    } else {
        log.debug(`file://${path.join(appAsarPath, "dist/index.html")}`);
        const filePath = `file://${path.join(appAsarPath, "dist/index.html")}`;
        mainWindow.loadURL(filePath);
        // mainWindow.removeMenu();
    }

    mainWindow.on("minimize", () => {
        mainWindow.isVisible() ? mainWindow.hide() : mainWindow.show();
    });
    mainWindow.on("close", async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const choice = dialog.showMessageBoxSync(mainWindow, {
            type: "question",
            title: i18n.__("Exit App"),
            message: i18n.__("Are you sure you want to exit?"),
            buttons: [i18n.__("No"), i18n.__("Yes")],
        });

        if (choice === 1) {
            mainWindow = null;
            app.exit();
        }
    });

    // Show the main window when it's ready
    mainWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (splashWindow) splashWindow.close();
            mainWindow.center();
            mainWindow.show();
        }, 3000);
    });
};

const createSplashWindow = () => {
    splashWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    frame: false,
    show: true,
    transparent: false,
    webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    });
    splashWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "src/services/preload.html"));
    splashWindow.center();

    log.debug("Started updateLicenseInfo");
    logger.debug(`Updated license info`);

    splashWindow.on("closed", () => {
        splashWindow = null;
    });
};

app.on("ready", async () => {
    log.debug("App ready");
    const serverPath = isDev
    ? path.join(__dirname, "src/services/server.js")
    : path.join(appAsarPath, "src/services/server.js");
    require(serverPath);
    log.debug("Backend started");

    createSplashWindow();

    logger.debug(`Created Splash Window`);

    let iconPath = path.join(appAsarPath, "dist/assets/img/icons/icon_win.ico");
    if (isDev)
    iconPath = path.join(__dirname, "dist/assets/img/icons/icon_win.ico");
    const icon = nativeImage.createFromPath(iconPath);
    tray = new Tray(icon);
    tray.setContextMenu(
        Menu.buildFromTemplate([
            {
                label: i18n.__("Show/Hide"),
                click: function () {
                    mainWindow.isVisible() ? mainWindow.hide() : mainWindow.show();
                },
                },
                {
                label: i18n.__("Quit"),
                click: function () {
                    isQuiting = true;
                    mainWindow.close();
                    app.quit();
                },
            },
        ])
    );
    tray.setToolTip(appName);
    tray.on("click", () => {
        mainWindow.isVisible() ? mainWindow.hide() : mainWindow.show();
    });
    logger.debug("Created tray");
    createMainWindow();
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
    app.quit();
});

app.on("before-quit", () => {
    if (serverProcess) serverProcess.kill();
});

process.on("uncaughtException", async (err) => {
    if (splashWindow) {
        splashWindow.hide();
        splashWindow = null;
    }
    if (mainWindow) {
        mainWindow.hide();
        mainWindow = null;
    }
    const errorMsg = `Uncaught Exception: ${err.stack}\n`;
    logger.error(errorMsg);
    showErrorDialog(
    i18n.__("An uncaught exception occurred") +
        ":\n" +
        err.message +
        "\n" +
        err.stack
    );

    app.quit();
});

function showErrorDialog(message) {
    dialog.showErrorBox(i18n.__("Error"), message);
}
```

index.js

```
let express = require("express");
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const { sequelize } = require("./database/sequelize");
const seederPartner = require("./database/seeder/partner.seeder");
const seederSoftware = require("./database/seeder/software.seeder");
const seederSetting = require("./database/seeder/setting.seeder");

sequelize
    .sync
    // { alter: true, force: true }
    ()
    .then(async () => {
        await seederPartner();
        await seederSoftware();
        await seederSetting();
    });

// Routes
const indexRoute = require("./routes/index.route");

const backendSvr = express();
backendSvr.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        status: "success",
        message: "Server is running",
    });
});
// backendSvr.use(cors());

backendSvr.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    res.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization");
    res.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "baseurl");
    res.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "companytaxcode");
    res.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "software");
    next();
});

backendSvr.use(bodyParser.json());
backendSvr.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

backendSvr.use("/", indexRoute);

backendSvr.use("*", function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404);

    // respond with html page
    if (req.accepts("html")) {
        return res.send("Access denied");
    }

    // respond with json
    if (req.accepts("json")) {
        return res.json({
            success: false,
            data: null,
            errors: {
                code: "NOT_FOUND",
                message: "Not found",
            },
        });
    }

    return res.type("txt").send(__("Not found"));
});

module.exports = backendSvr;
```

forge.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    packagerConfig: {
        asar: true,
        name: "KIN",
        appBundleId: "vn.kin.KIN",
        appCategoryType: "public.app-category.utilities",
        icon: "src/assets/img/icons/favicon",
        ignore: [
            (file) =>
            file.startsWith("@types/") && !file.startsWith("@types/express"),
            /\/node_modules\/(electron-packager|electron-prebuilt|electron|.cli-ngcc|.package-lock.json|__ngcc_entry_points__.json)($|\/)/,
            /\/(test|tests|docs|website|\.(md|markdown|gitignore|npmignore|yarnrc|yarnignore))$/,
            "/^/node_modules/@[^/]+/[^/]+/",
            "/node_modules/@electron-forge",
            "/node_modules/angular",
            "/node_modules/@angular",
            "/node_modules/rxjs",
            "/node_modules/zone.js",
            "/node_modules/tslib",
            "/node_modules/@types",
            "/node_modules/typescript",
            /\/src\/(app|assets|environments|libs|gate.css|gate.html|gate.js|main.ts|index.html)($|\/)/,
            "thunder-tests",
            "locales",
            "Diagram.drawio",
            "styles.css",
            "error.log",
            ".vscode",
            ".angular",
            ".editorconfig",
            ".eslintrc",
            "angular.json",
            "forge.config.js",
            "README.md",
            "tsconfig*.json",
            "tsconfig.*.json",
        ],
        asarUnpack: [
            // add any files or folders that need to be unpacked from the ASAR archive
            "**/file-to-unpack.txt",
            "folder-to-unpack/**/*",
        ],
    },
    build: {
        appId: "vn.kin.KIN"",
        productName: "KIN",
        electronLanguages: ["vi", "en_US"],
        mac: {
            icon: "src/assets/img/icons/icon_mac.icns",
        },
        win: {
            icon: "src/assets/img/icons/icon_win.ico",
        },
        linux: {
            icon: "src/assets/img/icons/icon_linux.png",
        },
    },
    rebuildConfig: {},
    makers: [
        {
            name: "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
            config: {
                icon: "src/assets/img/icons/icon_win.ico",
            },
        },
        {
          name: "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          platforms: ["darwin"],
        },
        {
            name: "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
            config: {},
        },
        {
            name: "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
            config: {},
        },
    ],
};
```